# Move ICONS Material UI in a NavBar to Right ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am creating my navbar and I am using two ui matter icons, which appear by default on the left side of the navbar, but I want to put them on the right side with justifyContent and alignItems but they don't move

```
icons: {
  width: '100%',
  position: 'relative',
  justifyContent: 'right',
  alignItems: 'right',
  display: 'flex',
  },
```

the idea is to move the icons to the right but this doesn't work for me, what should i do

Comment: Please share a minimal working example

Comment: Yes, you may modify this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1l8ej?file=/demo.js), save it, and share the link in your question description.

Comment: I need to move the icons to the right side of the navbar, but the justifycontent and align items properties do not work for me, what will happen? What I need?